# Speed Ramp Metadata for Slo-Mo Videos

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

In the Photos and Camera apps, viewing a slo-mo video allows the user to set times for ramps that affect the rate at which the video is played.

When importing videos into my app via UIImagePickerController, these ramps seem to be included in the asset I get. However, I’m writing a custom image picker controller and the ramps are no longer automatically included in the asset. I figure I have to wrap this asset in an AVMutableComposition and then add the speed ramps myself, but I can’t seem to find the ramp metadata anywhere.

Are the speed ramping metadata accessible anywhere?